# FB graph API problems with reading posts (type=status)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to analize a large number of posts from varoius pages for my bachelor thesis. Therefore I'm using a tool called Facepager which uses the graph API to fetch data from Facebook. 
I need the following data:
`id`, `link`, `type`, `from` and the count of likes, shares and comments (just the numbers, no further info!). In general, everything is working just fine, only posts classified `type=status` behave strangely. For some of these posts, there is no data shown about like, share and comment counts, further more there is no link given. But as mentioned before, this only happens sometimes! I searched for the affected posts manually on facebook and some of them had a large number of likes, shares or comments.

I also tried to fetch data with graph API explorer with similar results.

Is there any reason why it isn't possible to get share, like and comment count on some of the posts classified `type=status`?
Additionally, I'm planning to use the ID or if invalid, the link to open specific posts in my browser. This is not possible for some of the status posts either.

Sorry for that newbie question, it would be amazing if I could get an answer because at the moment I am quite desperate because this is really important for my bachelor thesis. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Because this kind of post is a post which "CAN NOT BE VIEWED".

ex: "xxxx likes a link", or "XXX commented on a post".

I suggest that you should filter out these posts by yourself.